# Squeak which selector sets rotation of TextMorph?

Tags: squeak

I can rotate a TextMorph in Morphic but cannot find the method for rotating it. I want to use it during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
aTextMorph addFlexShell rotationDegrees: 45.0
```

`#addFlexShell` wraps the TextMorph in a TransformationMorph that can be used to apply the transformations. When you apply the rotation via a morph's halo, it also adds the TransformationMorph. You may want to store it in a variable to access it again later:

```
flexShell := aTextMorph addFlexShell.
flexShell rotationDegrees: 45.0.
"..."
```

---

If you write this in a method and you need the flex shell (for transformation purposes) after the method has ended, add an instance variable to your class and save the flex shell in it:

```
Object subclassNamed: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: 'transformationOfMyMorph myMorph'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'MyPackage'

myMethod
    myMorph := TextMorph new contents: 'rotated text'.
    transformationOfMyMorph := myMorph addFlexShell.

rotateFurther
    transformationOfMyMorph rotationDegrees: transformationOfMyMorph rotationDegrees + 5.0.
```

If you only need the flex shell in one method, use a temporary (local) variable:

```
myMethod
    | flexShell |
    myMorph := TextMorph new. "..."
    flexShell := myMorph addFlexShell.
    "..."
```

Comment: ok I wondered if it was something like that. I still don't get the  process for saving a created morphic in a variable. Do I use a global variable that just lives in my image forever? or is there a way to create a subclass by accessing the variable? Can you point me to an explanation of the process. I have read so much but it is not yet clear?

Comment: There are multiple options: temporary (local) variables, instance variables, class variables. Depending on what you want to do and how long you need to refer to the morph, one is preferrabe over the other. Explaining them all is too much for a comment. Have you had a look at the book Squeak by Example? It is available as a download.

Comment: I have amended the answer with examples of instance variable and temporary variable usage.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I can definitely rotate things now and feel that I am close to understanding  saving a morph in a class instance variable.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note for further questions or communication with Smalltalkers that "instance variable" and "class instance variable" are two different things (and "class (pool) variable" is a third thing). That which I show in my answer is an "instance variable".